# Highcharts not starting at give start time

Tags: highcharts

Basically, I get the data from server for a given start and end time. If given time range is 1-Sep to 1-Oct and data returned by the server is from 15-Sep to 1-Oct only, then Highcharts does not show the duration 1-Sep to 1-Oct during which there was no data.

How do I make Highcharts to show this blank space.

Comment: Show your options object so we can see where you are starting from.

Comment: Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/max-200/) from the documentation of the maxValue on a y-axis, it's similar for the x-axis, and here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BntDf/1/) of your scenario

Comment: Thanks Sweko. I used [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes()) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can set min/max values on xAxis, but will be helfpul if you send us your live example.

Comment: Thanks. I was using highcharts as a directive in AngularJS so things became complex. I used the `setExtremes` method when my series data was changed. All is good now.